# Are let definitions in a Swift class allocated only once, or per instance?

Tags: swift

Let's say I have the following simple Swift class:

```
class Burrito {
    enum Ingredients {
        case beans, cheese, lettuce, beef, chicken, chorizo
    }

    private let meats : Set<Ingredients> = [.beef, .chicken, .chorizo]

    var fillings : Set<Ingredients>

    init (withIngredients: Set<Ingredients>) {
        fillings = withIngredients
    }

    func isVegetarian() -> Bool {
        if fillings.intersect(meats).count > 0  {
            return false
        }
        else {
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

If I create multiple instances of Burrito in an application, is the Set meats defined in memory once, separate from the memory allocated for each instance? I would assume that the compiler would optimize that way, but I haven't been able to find an answer on this yet.

**EDIT**

With the great help from the accepted answer, and the comments about the logic in the isVegetarian() method, here is the modified class.  Thanks everybody!

```
class Burrito {
    enum Ingredients {
        case beans, cheese, lettuce, beef, chicken, chorizo
    }

    private static let meats : Set<Ingredients> = [.beef, .chicken, .chorizo]

    var fillings : Set<Ingredients>

    init (withIngredients: Set<Ingredients>) {
        fillings = withIngredients
    }

    func isVegetarian() -> Bool {
        return fillings.intersect(Burrito.meats).isEmpty
    }

    // All burritos are delicious
    func isDelicious() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: `fillings.intersect(meats).count > 0` is an expression that returns a `Bool`. You don't need to wrap it in an `if`/`else` and manually `return` `true`/`false`. You can just use: `return !(fillings.intersect(meats).count > 0)`

Comment: Nice catch. I threw this together quickly to try out some stuff with unit tests and wasn't thinking clearly.

Comment: @AMomchilov Or just `return fillings.intersect(meats).isEmpty` ;)

Comment: @originaluser2 ooo yes, I like it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`meats` is an instance variable of the class. A new instance of `meats` will be made for every new instance (object) made from the class.

You can use the `static` keyword to make it a static variable, which will make it so there is only one instance of the `meats` variable, which is shared among all members of the class.

Immutable instance variables are typically used to be object-wide constants (rather than class-wide, like immutable static variables), which can have independent definitions for each object. In this case, the definition is static, so a smart compiler *could* optimize it into a static variable. Regardless, you should explicitly mark this `static` to communicate to users the intent of this variable.

Comment: Okay, I was getting an error that "Static member cannot be used on instance of type 'Burrito'." Should I then use `private static let meats : Set<Ingredients> = [.beef, .chicken, .chorizo]` for the definition, and then access it with `Burrito.meats` in functions?

Comment: Yes, Swift only allows you to call static members on types, not instances.